# swift get nil value in alertview textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I use SCLAlertView Framework as my Alert View.
https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift

I create an alertview with textfield. Here is the code.

```
let emailSubmit: UITextField = UITextField()
let passwordSubmit: UITextField = UITextField()
var email: String?
var password: String?

//This function call when loginbutton tapped
func showLogin(){

    let alertView = SCLAlertView()

    let emailSubmit = alertView.addTextField("Enter your Email")
    let passwordSubmit = alertView.addTextField("Password")

    email = emailSubmit.text
    password = passwordSubmit.text
    passwordSubmit.secureTextEntry = true

    alertView.addButton("Confirm", target:self, selector:#selector(ViewController.submitLogin))

    alertView.showTitle(
      "Login",
      subTitle: "",
      duration: nil,
      completeText: "Cancel",
      style: .Info)
  }
```

It required me to add a function for the button. The function name is submitLogin. It use to send the login detail(`textfield.text`) to the back-end server. However, it only return nil value after i click the submit button 
    It is the submit login button function

```
func submitLogin(){
let email = emailSubmit.text!
let password = passwordSubmit.text!

print("\(email),\(password)")
}
```

**However, It display nil when I click the submit button** Can anyone point out what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code should be like this:

```
var email: String?
var password: String?

//This function call when loginbutton tapped
@IBAction func showLogin(){

    let alertView = SCLAlertView()

    let emailSubmit = alertView.addTextField("Enter your Email")
    let passwordSubmit = alertView.addTextField("Password")

    passwordSubmit.secureTextEntry = true

    alertView.addButton("Confirm") {
        self.email = emailSubmit.text
        self.password = passwordSubmit.text

        self.submitLogin()
    }

    alertView.showTitle(
        "Login",
        subTitle: "",
        duration: nil,
        completeText: "Cancel",
        style: .Info)
}

func submitLogin(){
    print("\(email),\(password)")
}
```

**Explanation:**

In your code the line `password = passwordSubmit.text` is setting value of `var password` to  `nil` before user presses the confirm button, same with `var email`.

And there is not need to Define email and password textfields, since alertview will create textfields within itself.

Comment: omg... I should not create the sector to call the function. It will be more complicated. Thanks mate ! Well Explanation !

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two different `emailSubmit` and `passwordSubmit` variables present in your code. The one outside the function `showLogin` is the one you are using in `submitLogin` method but those fields are initialized without any value on lines 1 and 2. There is an another instance initialized and added to the `SCLAlertView` inside the `showLogin` method and displayed but its value is not used otherwise.

You should probably use `blocks` like how it is suggested in the [sample code](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift#add-text-fields)

Comment: oh yes! I should use block!!